# How to bind ColorBrush from inside ControlTemplate to a custom property outside of ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

This binding is driving me crazy, tried all sort of (even supposedly identical) solutions from stackoverflow. I cannot figure out why a binding does not work...

Problem:

I have a style with a ControlTemplate that is applied to a GridViewColumnHeader. This is the style with the ControlTemplate property:

```
    <Style x:Key="GridHeaderWithInkColor" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
              <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="White">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10" Orientation="Vertical">
                 <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5" 
                                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Left"
                                                   FontSize="24" Foreground="White"/>
                <Rectangle Height="15" Width="70" Margin="10" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="???????????????"/>                                                        
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
             </StackPanel>
           </Border>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I use the template as following in a GridViewHeaderColumn:

```
<GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridHeaderWithInkColor}" local:ExtendedProps.InkColor="{Binding MachineInfo.BarColorsList[0]}"/>
```

`local:ExtendedProps.InkColor` is a property I defined myself to be able to use it in xaml.

**Question is:

1. How can I bind SolidColorBrush inside ControlTemplate to property local:ExtendedProps.InkColor in GridViewColumn at the time of use.**

I tried this (and other variations, templatebindings, etc.) with no luck:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DataContext.IsItemSelected,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewColumn}}"/>
```

The two things that might be doing my life difficult are (I think):

- The SolidColorBrush is nested in other controls.
- The property I try to use is a custom-defined property (I am sure it is correctly defined).

Comment: In case `ExtendedProps.InkColor` is a correctly declared attched property, you would bind to it by `Color="{Binding Path=(local:ExtendedProps.InkColor), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewColumn}}"`. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#propertypath-for-objects-in-data-binding

Comment: I already tried exactly that and it is not working. Maybe the nesting has something to do? Take into account that the target of the controltemplate is a GridViewColumnHeader, but the property local:ExtendedProps.InkColor is set in GridViewColumn (I assume it is its parent).

Comment: Maybe the property isn't declared correctly. Are there any data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I bind `SolidColorBrush` inside `ControlTemplate` to property `local:ExtendedProps.InkColor` in `GridViewColumn` at the time of use.

The `GridViewColumnHeader` has a `Column` property that you can use to bind a property of the `GridViewColumn`:

```
Color="{Binding Path=Column.(local:ExtendedProps.InkColor), 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader}}"
```

The column isn't a visual ancestor of the header so using `{RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewColumn}` won't work.

Comment: Amazing. It did it!